# this and DOM on-event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom

The following statement on MDN seems not true:

> When the event handler is invoked, the this keyword inside the handler
> is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered.
> ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers))

This statement is about `an on<...> event handler` not `addEventListener`.

```
<p><a id="link" href="#" onclick="EventHandler();">click me</a></p>

<script>
    function EventHandler() {
        console.log(this); 
    //the this keyword inside the handler is NOT set to the DOM element
    //it sets to the window object
}
</script>
```

which contradicts with the statement on MDN.

*Of course, you can pass the `this` as an parameter to `EventHandler` or simply use `addEventListener`.But that is off topic.*

The topic of the question is`this` and `an on<...> event handler`.

My question is: Is that my understandig is not correct or is the statement on MDN is not correct?

Comment: I don't see any question there.  I see a *"TBD (non-capturing listener)"*in that article... it's is not like the final word of anything. That site is maintained by community and I believe there is an option to suggest edits. What is your question for stackoverflow community actually?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Feedback *"First of all, if you've seen a problem with the documentation, you should always feel free to correct it yourself"*

Comment: My question is: Is that my understandig is not correct or is the statement on MDN is not correct?

Comment: I can not simply modify other people's content just because I think it is not correct. Who can be that confident? At least I should listen to other peers opinions before I do so.

Comment: Totally agree. You should [edit] your post and update it so that the intention of post is clear and people know what sort of answer you're expecting. Right now it simply states your findings.

Comment: Calling a function means you lose the context, unless you specifically pass it on. `onclick="EventHandler.call(this,event);"`

Answer (score 1):

This statement is true whenever the event handler [is inlined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_in%E2%80%93line_event_handler), as it's stated in the link right after the sentence you quoted.

But, in your case, [MDN specify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) :

> When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the
> element the event fired from **(some browsers do not follow this
> convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than
> addEventListener)**.

I've tested in latest Chrome & FF, these browsers don't follow this convention.

Comment: `some browsers`? it should be `The majority of the browsers`.

Comment: Maybe the person who wrote that should tell the readers which browsers `follow this convention`? Maybe IE6?

Comment: Indeed. Anyway, the warning is told. You could contribute to the docs by providing your own test results on major browsers if you want to help !

Comment: As to the `in–line event handler`, I think `onclick="EventHandler();"` in my question  is  `in–line event handler`.

Comment: OP is asking about inline event handlers, also you are questing from a different article... the one OP quoted does seem to have incorrect info/misleading

Comment: @J.Joe I don't think it is. Test a real inline handler, like `onclick="console.log(this)"`, you'll see it logs what's expected.

Comment: @TJ I'm quoting from the docs linked just after the OP's quoted part. After all, I agree the original quote is misleading, but the linked detailed doc isn't.

Comment: @Bigood You just passed the `this`as an parameter in `onclick="console.log(this)"`. I can do that too if I write `onclick="EventHandler(this);` and modify `EventHandler` function. The `in–line event handler` is compared with `addEventListener`.IMO.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs, `this` inside event listeners/handlers will always be the current target of the event:

- [Event listeners](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener-invoke):

  > Call *listener*'s **callback**'s `handleEvent`, with the event passed
  >   to this algorithm as the first argument and *event*'s `currentTarget`
  >   attribute value as [callback this value](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#dfn-callback-this-value).
- [Event handlers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm)

  > - If *E* is an [`ErrorEvent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#errorevent) object and the [event handler IDL attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes)'s type is [`OnErrorEventHandler`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#onerroreventhandler)
  >
  >   [Invoke](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#errorevent) *callback* with five arguments, [...] and with the *callback this value* set to *E*'s `currentTarget`.
  > - Otherwise
  >
  >   [Invoke](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#errorevent) *callback* with one argument, the value of which is the [`Event`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#errorevent) object *E*, with the *callback this value* set to
  >     *E*'s `currentTarget`.